# Не работает canvas.create_image()

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пытаюсь сделать свою игру. Для этого мне нужно загрузить картинку на canvas. Я написал такой код:

```
img = Image.open("/home/martos/Documents/code/python/RPG_P:1/images/skeleton.jpg")
enemyimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
c.create_image(50,50,image=enemyimg)
```

Проблема в том, что картинка не отображается, но при этом определяется верно, то есть проблема в другом. Я перерыл весь интернет, но ничего не сработало.

Помогите мне, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Наверное двоеточие в имени директории `:` мешает

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, сама фотография определяется правильно, это я проверил. Добавлю это в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема, но смог решить. Смотри как:

```
img=PhotoImage(file='icon.png')
# если у тебя не сработает, то пиши полный путь, а перед кавычками напиши r

d=c.create_image(50,50,image=img)
```